# Heap Book Box Packing

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, heapsort

I am attempting to write a program that reads in an order of books, stores them in a heap and implements a greedy algorithm to pack the books into boxes efficiently based on weight;

I am having trouble with implementing the heap correctly.

The method I am using to add to the Heap is called addLastChild(). It should find the next spot in the heap and insert the new book and restructure according to its weight.

here is the add code:

```
public void addLastChild(Book newBook)
{
    Book[] pathList = new Book[30];
    int tracker = 0;

    int cnt = BookCnt+1;
    String path = "";
    while(cnt >= 1) 
    {
        path = (cnt %2) + path;
        cnt = cnt / 2;
    }

    Book c = root;

    if(root!=null)
    {
        pathList[tracker]=root;
        tracker++;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < path.length()-1; i++){
        if(path.charAt(i)== '0') {

            c = c.left;
            pathList[tracker]=c;
            tracker++;
        } else {

            c = c.right;
            pathList[tracker]=c;
            tracker++;
        }
    }
    if(path.length() == 1)
    {
        root = newBook;
    } 
    else if(path.charAt(path.length()-1)== '0') {
        c.left = newBook;
        pathList[tracker]=c.left;
        tracker++;

    } 
    else
    {
        c.right = newBook;
        pathList[tracker]=c.right;
        tracker++;
    }
    BookCnt++;

    boolean doTrickle = false;
    if(tracker>=2)
    {
        doTrickle = true;
    }

    while(doTrickle == true)
    {
        Book temp = new Book(pathList[tracker-2].refNumber, pathList[tracker-2].weight, pathList[tracker-2].title, null,null);
        //int refNumber, int weight, String title, Book left, Book right
        print(root,"    ");

        if(pathList[tracker-1].weight > pathList[tracker-2].weight)
        {

            pathList[tracker-2].refNumber=pathList[tracker-1].refNumber;

            pathList[tracker-2].title=pathList[tracker-1].title;
            pathList[tracker-2].weight=pathList[tracker-1].weight;

            if(pathList[tracker-2].left == pathList[tracker-1])
            {
                pathList[tracker-2].left = temp;
            }
            if(pathList[tracker-2].right == pathList[tracker-1])
            {
                pathList[tracker-2].right = temp;
            }

            tracker--;

            System.out.println("we trickled");
            print(root,"    ");
        }
        else
        {
            doTrickle =false;
        }
    }

}
```

The 2 methods that I am using to remove from the Heap are removeLastChild() and remove() the removeLastChild() method returns the last book in the Heap, and the remove() should return the book with the largest weight and replace the root with the last Book, then restructure the heap accordingly.

Here is the removal Code that is giving me trouble:

```
Book removeLastChild() {
    int cnt = BookCnt;
    String path = "";
    while(cnt >= 1) 
    {
        path = (cnt %2) + path;
        cnt = cnt / 2;
    }

    Book returnBook = null;
    Book c = root;
    for(int i = 1; i < path.length()-1; i++){
        if(path.charAt(i)== '0') {
            c = c.left;
        } else {
            c = c.right;
        }
    }
    if(path.length() == 1)
    {
        returnBook = root;
        root = null;
    } 
    else if(path.charAt(path.length()-1)== '0') {
        returnBook = c.left;
        c.left = null;
    } 
    else
    {
        returnBook = c.right;
        c.right = null;
    }
    BookCnt--;
    return returnBook;
}

Book remove()
{

    Book largest =root; 
    root = removeLastChild();

    if(largest.left!= null)
    {
        root.left = largest.left;
    }
    if(largest.right!= null)
    {
        root.right = largest.right;
    }



    Book cur = root;

    if(root!= null)
    {
        while(cur.left !=null && cur.right!= null)
        {
            if(cur.weight<cur.left.weight || cur.weight<cur.right.weight)
            {
                Book temp = new Book(cur.refNumber, cur.weight, cur.title, null, null);
                //int refNumber, int weight, String title, Book left, Book right

                if(cur.left.weight>cur.right.weight)
                {
                        cur.refNumber = cur.left.refNumber;

                    cur.title = cur.left.title;
                    cur.weight = cur.left.weight;


                    cur.left.refNumber = temp.refNumber;
                    cur.left.weight = temp.weight;
                    cur.left.title = temp.title;
                    cur = cur.left;

                }
                else
                {

                    cur.refNumber = cur.right.refNumber;

                    cur.title = cur.right.title;
                    cur.weight = cur.right.weight;

                    cur.right.refNumber = temp.refNumber;
                    cur.right.weight = temp.weight;
                    cur.right.title = temp.title;
                    cur = cur.right;

                }

            }
            else
            {
                return largest;
            }
        }
    }
    return largest;

}
```

Thanks for the Help!

I'm happy to clarify anything that I didn't communicate clearly.

Comment: So, where's your problem? What happens? What should happen?

Comment: My Heap does not build correctly somehow. It should have no empty nodes except at the end and every node's parent should be larger than itself. if you insert books with weight values of { 57, 12, 5, 31, 3,  27, 13, 30, 7, 33, 10, 14} you will find everything works correctly until the weight 33 is entered.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit what you are trying to achieve here, isn't your problem similar to the [greedy aproximation algorithm for the Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Greedy_approximation_algorithm)?

Comment: yes that is what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I might suggest an alternative to your heap implementation, and given your objective of the greedy algorithm for the Knapsack problem, why no not simply use a [PriorityQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)?

From the documentation: "An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap. The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time (...)"

If your book class implements the Comparable interface like this (the Book in the example is very simplified):

```
    class Book implements Comparable<Book>{
        public String title;
        public int weight;

        public Book(int weight, String title) {
            this.weight = weight;
            this.title = title;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Book anotherBook) {
            return weight - anotherBook.weight;
        }
    }
```

The natural ordering of your books should go from the book with the least weight to the book with the most weight.

Using the Book class in a priority queue:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book book1 = new Book(10,"a");
        Book book2 = new Book(11,"b");
        Book book3 = new Book(20,"c");
        Book book4 = new Book(20,"d");
        Book book5 = new Book(11,"e");

        PriorityQueue<Book> bookQueue = new PriorityQueue<Book>();
        bookQueue.add(book1);
        bookQueue.add(book2);
        bookQueue.add(book3);
        bookQueue.add(book4);
        bookQueue.add(book5);

        while(!bookQueue.isEmpty()){
            Book book = bookQueue.poll();
            System.out.println(book.title + " - " + book.weight);
        }
    }
```

You should be able to iterate the books the way you need to put them in your boxes.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm afraid I understand how to make it work with a priority queue. I want to be sure I understand linked structures so I would like to stick with the linked Heap approach. Thanks tho!